# How to insert records into a referenced table before inserting into the origin table?

Tags: postgresql

I happen to stumble upon the use case where it will be more convenient to insert one or more referenced records before inserting the record to the origin table. As an example, we can use the following use case...

For some reason, we're trying to put two types of animals with different genders together. Please consider the following DDL:

```sql
create table animals (
  id serial primary key,
  name text unique not null
);

create table combinations (
  id serial primary key,
  male_animal_id int references animals not null,
  female_animal_id int references animals not null
);
```

Now the question is: how to insert a combination without knowing or having the animal `id`'s but just the animal `name`'s, what might not still need to be created?

This is what I got thus far (checkout [the full dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b86c5e0dc846fb483ac3577a2b464576)):

```sql
create or replace function add_combi(p_male text, p_female text)
  returns void
  language sql
  as $$

with new_records as (
  insert into animals (name)
  values (p_male), (p_female)
  on conflict (name) do nothing
  returning *
)
insert into combinations (male_animal_id, female_animal_id)
select
  m.id as male,
  f.id as female
  from new_records m, new_records f
  where m.name = p_male
    and f.name = p_female
union
select
  m.id as male,
  f.id as female
  from animals m, animals f
  where m.name = p_male
    and f.name = p_female;
    
$$;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work when one of the animal `name`already exists and the other one doesn't.

Preferences/requirements:

- It should reuse already existing animals.
- It should be written as a stored procedure/function.
- The whole operation should be done in one query, so the function should be `language sql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hackering I've found the (or a) solution!

For each foreign key value in the `combinations` table a separate select statement should be created and united with the other statements. All those statements then should be used as a subquery where the columns are then aggregated on. Resulting in the following:

```sql
create or replace function add_combi(p_male text, p_female text)
  returns void
  language sql
  as $$

with new_records as (
  insert into animals (name)
  values (p_male), (p_female)
  on conflict (name) do nothing
  returning *
)
insert into combinations (male_animal_id, female_animal_id)
select max(male), max(female) from (
  select
    id as male,
    null as female
    from new_records
    where name = p_male
  union
  select
    null as male,
    id as female
    from new_records
    where name = p_female
  union
  select
    id as male,
    null as female
    from animals
    where name = p_male
  union
  select
    null as male,
    id as female
    from animals
    where name = p_female
  ) r;

$$;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b89c0b9771ff0e05df36026cf4258a06)